# Don't extract wrong substrings/numbers

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, substring

I am working with address data in PostgreSQL and need to extract 4-digit postal codes.

I have some addresses such as
'UNIT 1503 CENTRE RD CLAYTON VIC 3168 1503, AU'
where '3168' corresponds to my postal code.

Everything I have tried extracts '1503' as postal code which is wrong.
In the remaining addresses, 4-digit numbers that are NOT postal codes such as '1503' occur twice in the address. In most of the cases, the second number occurs before the comma (but I am not sure if this is the case for all).

The following code gives me a list with all 4-digit numbers:

```
select array_to_string(regexp_matches('1503 CENTRE RD CLAYTON VIC 3168 1503, AU', '\m[0-9]{4}\M', 'g'), '')
```

but when I update my column 'postal_code', only the first row is used.

I would need a code that first checks whether there are more than one 4-digit numbers. If this is the case, I need to implement the following rule (I don't know how):
"If there is more than one 4-digit number in the string, only extract the number that is unique (3168); get rid of the number that occurs twice".

Answer (score 1):

You are almost here.

```
with t(id,x) as (values
  (1,'1503 CENTRE RD CLAYTON VIC 3168 1503, AU'::text),
  (2,'1111 2222 3333 1111')) 
select id, n[1]
from t, regexp_matches(x, '\m\d{4}\M', 'g') as n 
group by id, n[1]
having count(*) = 1; -- Check for uniqueness
```